# How do I add a button to a SharePoint Modal using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a modal to display, it displays fine. I'm trying to add a button to the modal, the button should fire the acceptTerms() function, storing the cookie and then closing the modal.

I'm struggling to get a button on the modal. It adds the HTML, I can see it in the source, it's just not appearing.

I've tried something like this in the WebPart:

```
var acceptBtn = '<input type="button" style="width:75px;" value="I Accept" onclick="acceptTerms()">';
$('body').append(acceptBtn);
```

Here's the WebPart JS:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', showModalPopUp);  
});  

var agreed = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)Acknowledged\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
if(!agreed) {
    function showModalPopUp() {  
    //Set options for Modal PopUp  
    var options = {  
        url: '/path/to/my/terms/page.aspx', //Set the url of the page  
        title: 'Terms', //Set the title for the pop up  
        allowMaximize: false,  
        autosize: true,
        showClose: true,  
        width: 600,  
        height: 400, 
    };  
    //Invoke the modal dialog by passing in the options array variable  
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);  
    return false;  
    }
}

function acceptTerms() {
    var d = new Date();
    var expire = new Date(d);
    expire.setDate(d.getDate() + 365);
    document.cookie = "Acknowledged=true; Path=/; Expires="+expire;
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Yes);
}
```

Comment: Have just tried to add a button in the web part without appending it? `<button type='button' onclick......>I Accept</button>` and then your script after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so You are presenting the modal with some options, in the options You define the html You want to show

```
    url: '/path/to/my/terms/page.aspx'
```

so all html You want to show and JS logic with it should be in this page.

another way, but I guess not the best approach is to add the button to the modal layout with a jQuery trick (but please be aware it is rather not recommended way, as SharePoint modal framework should allow to show You input html in defined layout so it is not the best option to modify the layout. Your logic, as I said before, should be in the html (aspx) page You pass)
so the trick is to do this way:

```
     
      
        $(document).ready(function() {  
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', showModalPopUp);  
    });  

    var agreed = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)Acknowledged\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
    if(!agreed) {
        function showModalPopUp() {  
             createModal()
             $("#dlgTitleBtns .ms-dlgCloseBtn").before("");
             $("#dialogTitleSpan").attr("style","width:auto;");
        }
    }

    function createModal()
    {
    //Set options for Modal PopUp  
            var options = {  
                url: '/path/to/my/terms/page.aspx', //Set the url of the page  
                title: 'Terms', //Set the title for the pop up  
                allowMaximize: false,  
                autosize: true,
                showClose: true,  
                width: 600,  
                height: 400, 
            };  
            //Invoke the modal dialog by passing in the options array variable  
            SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options); 
    }

    function acceptTerms() {
        var d = new Date();
        var expire = new Date(d);
        expire.setDate(d.getDate() + 365);
        document.cookie = "Acknowledged=true; Path=/; Expires="+expire;
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Yes);
    }
```

or something similar :)... please be aware I did not test this, but this should give You the idea of the approach.
Similar solution may be found here -> [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/266bd562-9a0e-4163-8ca0-fdafd0e7907c/adding-html-buttons-to-the-layout-of-sharepoint-2013-modal-dialog?forum=sharepointdevelopment)